# Tensorflow: add a constraint based on probability output

Tags: python, tensorflow, constraints, probability

I am training a dataset by considering Tensorflow in Python for a supervised classification problem (3 classes).
My output is a vector returning the probability of each class: `p=[p_0, p_1, p_2]`.
However, based on the physic behind this problem, I should have the following constraint:

`min(p_0,p_2)<p_1<max(p_0, p_2)` or `p_1>max(p_0,p_2)`.

Otherway stated:

```
 - if a sample is labeled 2, the second highest probability should be for the class 1.
 - if a sample is labeled 0, the second highest probability should be for the class 1.
```

Do you know how to consider this in the code?

My guess is to add my own loss method in the compile function (as shown below) but I am not sure, and I do not know how to access to the probability vector.

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=myLossFunction, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Maybe another option would be to change the input label in a tricky way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your data captures this physics phenomenon, then your model will learn it. The model might get it wrong, but you'll never have a model that's 100% right.

Comment: So, do you want to find the right category, or do you want to find a probability distribution? Softmax is a specific activation function, maybe you should use your own

Comment: In fact, I would like to classify if a chemical corresponds to a "low", "medium" of "high" concentration. It seems not logical to get the highest probability to the "high" class if the second highest is for the "low" class. Even if I get a good accuracy and loss it seems not pertinent and it would be preferable to increase weights for other nodes even if it decreases the accuracy and/or increases the loss. At the end I want the right category but some behaviors about the conditional probabilities have to be respected